# Changing position of created "plotshape" on Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

The signals "RSI Buy" or "RSI Sell" appears directly above or below the bar and sometimes it's difficult to read it. Is it possible to change the position in the y-axis on the chart.

```
enter code here

//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", overlay=true, shorttitle="RSI Signals")

srcRSI = close
lenRSI = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")

//method color[enter image description here][1]
srcRSI1 = close
lenRSI1 = input(70, minval=1, title="RSI Up Standard")
srcRSI2 = close
lenRSI2 = input(30, minval=1, title="RSI Down Standard")

upRSI = rma(max(change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)
downRSI = rma(-min(change(srcRSI), 0), lenRSI)

rsiRSI = downRSI == 0 ? 100 : upRSI == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + upRSI / downRSI)

isup() =>
    rsiRSI[1] > lenRSI1 and rsiRSI <= lenRSI1
isdown() =>
    rsiRSI[1] < lenRSI2 and rsiRSI >= lenRSI2

plotshape(isup(), color=#FF0000, style=shape.triangledown, text="RSI Sell", textcolor=#FF0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(isdown(), color=#009900, style=shape.triangleup, text="RSI Buy", textcolor=#009900, location=location.belowbar, size=size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `plotshape()`'s `location=` arguments of with `location.absolute` and add any `y`(price) location for the label (`high + atr(10)` / `low - atr(10)`), as is shown in the example below:

```
plotshape(isup()? high + atr(10) : na, color=#FF0000, style=shape.triangledown, text="RSI Sell", textcolor=#FF0000, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(isdown()? low - atr(10) : na, color=#009900, style=shape.triangleup, text="RSI Buy", textcolor=#009900, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried that before unfortunately it still looks like this: https://www.tradingview.com/x/bLQNJGgP/

Comment: You can try to add a multiplier, for ex:     high + 5 * atr(10)